# Prioritize publications in Tridion 2009 SP1

Tags: publishing

Currently, whenever we publish a content file along with all the child publications, all the child publications get published in a random order. Is there a way I can configure the publication Target in CMS to sort out the publications and publish in the order of priority we provide ?

Comment: Hi raniworld, please consider posting this question on Tridion.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no Out-of-the-Box functionality for this. I also can't think of a elegant way you would even manage that given there are only 3 publishing priorities.

The only way I think you could achieve it, is to build a custom GUI extension which allows you to schedule each child publish action individually. A tool which allows you to select which child publications to publish too has been proposed at https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/wiki/PublishToChildren. You might consider joining the PowerTools team and extend that idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using these techniques, but they will not quite allow the behavior you are looking for. You could give the parent publication dedicated resource.

http://blog.building-blocks.com/filtering-prioritization-of-the-tridion-publish-queue

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if your problem is not so much that you want to control the order. Perhaps what you really want is for everything to publish simultaneously. In this case, I would suggest using the advanced publishing options to separate the rendering and deployment phases. By allowing a suitable time between the two, the rendering for all publications can be complete before the deployment takes place. This should give the result that you deploy to all publications more or less simultaneously. (Not exactly simultaneously, so you'd have to test it to see if you get accepatable results.)